# AngularJs: How to use ng-repeat object in ng-model as sub string. to generate dynamic ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use ng-repeat object in `ng-model` value as sub string.. can i use this?? My scenario is:

```
<form id="booking_form" name="booking_form" ng-app="myApp" ng-submit="tasksubmit()">
    <ul class="items-list">
        <li ng-repeat="task in taskslist | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp" class="items-list-item">
            <div class="items-list-item-image">
                <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tasksubmit{{task.id}}" />


                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="items-list-item-detail">
                <p>
                    <strong>{{task.title}}</strong>
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

in `< input type = checkbox >` i want to generate dynamic `ng-model` with prefix of tasksubmit (this is initialized in controller as `$scope.tasksubmit = {}` ). Any body please help me out in this problem.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add model with ngRepeat's instance property

Like this

```
<li ng-repeat="task in taskslist | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp" class="items-list-item">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="task.isChecked" />                 
</li>
```

You'll find value of `isChecked` from `$scope.taskslist`

<kbd>**[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/dnnqpva8/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Dear Anik, Thanks for you answer can you please more explain how can I find the ischecked value from `$scope.tasklist`. becasue i think we are not sending any task id via `task.id`.

Comment: supose you have only property id in  tasklist . it'll add isChecked in that object. so your current object will be `{id : 1, isChecked : false }`

Comment: @TechKid i have added fiddle 4 you

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want all `task.id` as property inside your `tasksubmit` object as you have initialized it as object in your controller so you can do as below:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="tasksubmit[task.id]" />
```

Comment: I'ave used this already but this solution doesn't work. in inspect element it doesn't fetch the {{task.id}} value i want to print the ng-model's value as tasksubmit.7 .. here it is snapshot http://prntscr.com/9jsy8d